# How to "duplicate" rows in a specific table(while auto-assigning a new ID)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create an identical copy of many records in a table. The table has a PK id, which of course will be different, in the freshly-copied records.

For example, let's say i have a `scrum_card` table, with the following non-unique columns: **name, description, board_id**

I have a dynamic array of id's of records, which i wish to duplicate: [34,56,32,3445,...]

How do i tell MYSQL, to fetch the data from **all those records**, and make a batch-insert of those same records?

In "human" syntax it would look something like this: "Select all columns(besides id) from scrum_card where the id's are [array of id's], then duplicate each found record".

Comment: Is the id column auto increment?

Comment: yes it is..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INSERT using a SELECT result set as the source, instead of a set of literal row tuples with VALUES(...).

```
INSERT INTO new_table (id, col1, col2, col3...)
SELECT NULL, col1, col2, col3...
FROM old_table
WHERE id IN (34,56,32,3445,...)
```

Using `NULL` in place of the id column in the SELECT will return NULL for each row, which will cause `new_table` to generate a new id value.

But SQL does not have any way to do a wildcard like "all columns except id," besides you typing the column names in.

Comment: I see, i'll try this. Just making sure: new_table and old_table are the same table, right? Because i'm duplicating records within the very same table.

Comment: Yes, you can send the result to the same table. I do this often to generate random test data, like when I want to create 1 million rows in a table, I start with one, then start doubling them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...` and in the list of columns do not include the `id`:

```
insert into scrum_card(name, description, board_id)
select name, description, board_id
from scrum_card 
where id in (34,56,32,3445,...)
```

Comment: Is there any way to "abstract" this, meaning not referencing the column names? I need to perform this operation on many tables. Bill Karwin says it's not possible to tell mysql to "select all besides id".

Comment: No there is no such statement like select * except.